# Building 32-bit Qt Mysql plugin fails with MinGw

Tags: mysql, windows, qt, qt4, mingw

I'm building a MySQL plugin for Qt 4.4.3 Open Source Edition ([Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/sql-driver.html#building-the-plugins-manually)), and using command:

```
cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\MySQL\include" "LIBS+=C:\MYSQL\MySQL Server <version>\lib\opt\libmysql.lib" mysql.pro
make
```

I manage to build it to my 64-bit Qt just fine using 64-bit MySQL dev files (using nmake). However, 32-bit build (with mingw-make) fails with linking problems:

```
Creating library file: c:\Coding\Qt\4.4.3\plugins\sqldrivers\libqsqlmysqld4.a
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_mysql.o(.text+0x10d): In function `Z5codecP8st_mysql':
...lots of same stuff...
```

The dev files installed by MySQL 5.1 32-bit and 64-bit library are also different: the 64-bit includes libmysql.dll and six .lib files, while 32-bit includes those **plus** six .pdb files. Relevant to this issue?

Is anyone able to build the 32-bit plugin with Qt 4.4.3/MinGW using MySQL 5.1? Suggestions?

Comment: Anyone care to try it and tell me if they succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mysql-noinstall-5.1.14-beta-win32

Comment: Thanks. I figured out it must've been the mysql package which was wrong, but apparently the new build is fixed. Thanks for testing it out.